# Jbox Access Requirements

Tags: electrical, wiring

The builder has a couple of jboxes for the upstairs cabinet lighting that is mounted flush with the ceiling.

I am finishing the basement and this area will have a dropped soffit ceiling in this area. Can I put an access panel in the soffit to be able to access the jbox or is it require to rerun longer wires to move the jbox down to the soffit?

[image: jbox]

Comment: How far from the finished wall/ceiling will the box end up? Your access panel (if allowed) probably needs to be big enough to allow a future maintainer to get both hands in to work on the box, not just to see that it's back there.

Comment: @nobody it's about 12". What you said makes sense and I'll take that into account when assessing the viability of an access panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access panels are acceptable from an electrical view. I have been challenged a couple of times in commercial work about fire rating (I'm not familiar with residential fire codes).

Comment: You can buy metal access panels, though, if you're worried about being challenged on fire pro. (I assume the challenges were regarding plastic panels.)